# Conventional way to find all .cpp .h files in a directory (include, src, etc...)

Tags: c++, c, compilation

I want to extract an example from a large codebase/API, but I would like to avoid using the designated build system, and manually find all the file dependencies into one big folder that I can just `g++ *.cpp`, and it will "just work". Is there any such method to do this?

```
main.cpp
project
│
├── src
│   ├── source.cpp
│   └── *.cpp
└── include
    ├── source.h
    └── *.h
```

Comment: Depend of your build system. CMake, makefile, solution from IDE, ...

Comment: @Jarod42 I am just using a text editor and terminal, something like `g++ main.cpp -I /path/to/include`, which produces a growing list of undefined references the more paths that are included.

Comment: You will also have to link in any external libraries, such as PortAudio. Again dependent on your build system, but usually results in a -L<path to library> and a -l<name of library> on the command line.

Comment: Ah. Doing it the hard way, eh? Are there any odd-looking files with names like *configure* or *makefile* floating around in the directory tree?

Comment: then depends of your shell and globbing capacity: `g++ ./**/*.cpp -I /path/to/include`. ;-) or `g++ \`find . -name "*.cpp"\` -I /path/to/include`

Comment: @user4581301 I have run `./configure && make` and everything seems to compile with `#include "portaudio.h"` and `portaudio.h` in the same folder as `main.cpp`, I would just prefer to link to `portaudio` without modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up writing a small script even though it probably isn't the easiest/most efficient way, it still achieves the result. It is pretty useful just to get a string containing all headers and source files which can be used in conjunction with `cp [headers] /path/to/dst` to create an simple ad-hoc structure for MVCE, code extraction, prototyping, etc...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <list>

/*
* Recursively navigates the file tree and finds all .h header files
* and all .cpp files, to be used to "scrape" large codebases
*   
*/

std::list<std::string> source_list = {};
std::list<std::string> header_list = {};

int is_dir(const char *path)
{
    struct stat statbuf;
    if (stat(path, &statbuf) != 0)
        return 0;
    return S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode);
}


void dirSearch(std::string p)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char path[100];

    std::string cd = "cd ";
    std::string ls = " && ls";
    std::string cmd = cd + p + ls;

    fp = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to run command\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (fgets(path, sizeof(path)-1, fp) != NULL) {

        std::string abs_path = p + "/" + path;

        // rm \n
        abs_path.pop_back();

        // any folder can be a path to search for headers in
        if ( is_dir(abs_path.c_str()) ) {
            dirSearch(abs_path);
        }
        // if not a directory, check if the file is a .cpp file and add to list of source files 
        else {
            std::string SOURCE_FILE_EXT = ".cpp";

            if (abs_path.substr(abs_path.size() - SOURCE_FILE_EXT.size(), abs_path.size()) == SOURCE_FILE_EXT) {
                source_list.push_back(abs_path);
            }

            std::string HEADER_FILE_EXT = ".h";

            if (abs_path.substr(abs_path.size() - HEADER_FILE_EXT.size(), abs_path.size()) == HEADER_FILE_EXT) {
                header_list.push_back(abs_path);
            }
        }
    }
    pclose(fp);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    dirSearch(argv[1]);

    std::string headers = "";
    std::string fsource = " ";
    
    // add header path
    for (std::string l : header_list) {
        all_header_files += " " + l;
    }
    // add source files
    for (std::string l : source_list) {
        all_source_files += " " + l;
    }

    std::cout << all_header_files << std::endl;
    std::cout << all_source_files << std::endl;
}
```

Here is an example usage:

```
g++ scrape_source.cpp -o scrape_source
./scrape_source PhysX-4.1

... PhysX-4.1/physx/src/fastxml/src/PsFastXml.cpp PhysX-4.1/physx/src/foundation/src/PsAllocator.cpp PhysX-4.1/physx/src/foundation/src/PsAssert.cpp PhysX-4.1/physx/src/foundation/src/PsFoundation.cpp PhysX-4.1/physx/src/foundation/src/PsMathUtils.cpp PhysX-4.1/physx/src/foundation/src/PsString.cpp PhysX-4.1/physx/src/foundation/src/PsTempAllocator.cpp PhysX-4.1/physx/src/foundation/src/PsUtilities.cpp PhysX-4.1/physx/src/foundation/src/unix/PsUnixAtomic.cpp PhysX-4.1/physx/src/foundation/src/unix/PsUnixCpu.cpp PhysX-4.1/physx/src/foundation/src/unix/PsUnixFPU.cpp PhysX-4.1/physx/src/foundation/src/unix/PsUnixMutex.cpp PhysX-4.1/physx/src/foundation/src/unix/PsUnixPrintString.cpp PhysX-4.1/physx/src/foundation/src/unix/PsUnixSList.cpp PhysX-4.1/physx/src/foundation/src/unix/PsUnixSocket.cpp PhysX-4.1/physx/src/foundation/src/unix/PsUnixSync.cpp PhysX-4.1/physx/src/foundation/src/unix/PsUnixThread.cpp PhysX-4.1/physx/src/foundation/src/unix/PsUnixTime.cpp PhysX-4.1/physx/src/foundation/src/windows/PsUWPThread.cpp PhysX-4.1/physx/src/foundation/src/windows/PsWindowsAtomic.cpp PhysX-4.1/physx/src/foundation/src/windows/PsWindowsCpu.cpp ...
```